# What are all the differences between src and data-src attributes?

Tags: html, image

What are differences and consequences (both good and bad) of using either `data-src` or `src` attribute of `img` tag? Can I achieve the same results using both? If so, when should be used each of them?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The attributes `src` and `data-src` have nothing in common, except that they are both allowed by HTML5 CR and they both contain the letters `src`. Everything else is different.

The `src` attribute is defined in HTML specs, and it has a functional meaning.

The `data-src` attribute is just one of the infinite set of `data-*` attributes, which have no defined meaning but can be used to include invisible data in an element, for use in scripting (or styling).

Comment: Angular.js also uses data-src for late binding of urls based on the model

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer :) just about to use jQuery.lazy and was not sure what was up with the scr's

Answer (score 31):

If you want the image to load and display a particular image, then use `.src` to load that image URL.

If you want a piece of meta data (on any tag) that can contain a URL, then use `data-src` or any `data-xxx` that you want to select.

MDN documentation on data-xxxx attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset

Example of `src` on an image tag where the image loads the JPEG for you and displays it:

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://mydomain.com/foo.jpg">

<script>
    var imageUrl = document.getElementById("myImage").src;
</script>
```

Example of 'data-src' on a non-image tag where the image is not loaded yet - it's just a piece of meta data on the div tag:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-src="http://mydomain.com/foo.jpg">

<script>
    // in all browsers
    var imageUrl = document.getElementById("myDiv").getAttribute("data-src");

    // or in modern browsers
    var imageUrl = document.getElementById("myDiv").dataset.src;
</script>
```

Example of `data-src` on an image tag used as a place to store the URL of an alternate image:

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://mydomain.com/foo.jpg" data-src="http://mydomain.com/foo.jpg">

<script>
    var item = document.getElementById("myImage");
    // switch the image to the URL specified in data-src
    item.src = item.dataset.src;
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

src will render the value immediately and it’s the default for images, videos using a single source and iframes.

data-src is used when lazy loading to prevent the default image from loading when the page loads. Most lazy loading libraries will use intersection observer and copy the data-src value to src when it’s time to load the image.

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, this is what I was searching for. I'm scraping a website (https://avalaunchmedia.com/), and they have a slider that uses the concept explained in this answer. I was getting very confused with why the actual link to the image was in the `data-src` entry. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

The first `<img />` is invalid - `src` is a required attribute. `data-src` is an attribute than can be leveraged by, say, JavaScript, but has no presentational meaning.

Comment: @AdamPierzchała The gist is the same - there is no "either/or" to this question; `src` must be included. You use `data-` attributes to add extra data for a scripting language (like JavaScript) to leverage.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer says. If you're looking for the usage of `data-src` [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) is a popular one.

Answer (score -5):

Well the data src attribute is just used for binding data for example ASP.NET ...

[W3School src attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

[MSDN datasrc attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533709%28VS.85%29.aspx)