# How to use data-src and src?

Tags: html

I am encountering a problem with getting an image to display with the usage of `src` and `data-src` of the `img` tag.

The below work perfectly fine:

```
<img src = "img/testimage1.jpg"/>
```

The below code doesn't display anything:

```
<img data-src = "img/testimage1.jpg" alt="first"/>
```

Comment: data-src doesn't do anything by itself, for displaying an image, only the first one is correct

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 2):

[As already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320346/2083599), `data-src` is a simple `data-*` attribute of the HTML5 spec, while `src` defines the source of the image tag.

`data-*` attributes only have meaning for JS scripts.