# After setting up an SSL cert, css, scripts, and images are not loading but not getting errors

Tags: wordpress, ssl, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site that I installed a third party SSL certificate for.
The certificate seems to working correctly in that I have a padlock, but none of the styles, scripts, or images are loading (on the secure site only).

What's strange to me is that I don't see any errors about mixed content or any other errors in my console.

Wordpress site is set to https:// version in settings.  I've tried playing around with my WP plugins and activating/deactivating them.  I've also searched through my source code for instances of "http", but can't find any.  I've tried some of the suggested SSL WP plugins I've found online, but no luck so far.

Here are my secure and un-secure sites for reference.

https://114w41.com/
http://114w41.com/

Any suggestions of what else I could look into would be great!  Thank you!

Comment: Your tags are all wrong. You are using `data-src` attribute where you should use `src` attribute to specify URLs of images, styles, scripts, etc.

Comment: Thanks - I can try updating the WordPress theme (I didn't build this originally, now just trying to fix).  However, the non-secure site works perfectly using the exact same theme code.  Can you think of a reason why this might be?

Comment: There may be some script that takes content in `data-src` to do something with it, that works in HTTP and not in HTTPS. Use Developer Tools in your browser and compare what is happening in both cases. In all cases, the URLs should go in `src` and not in `data-src`, so I believe that even your HTTP case is wrong, even if it works "by chance" (or convoluted way). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970943/how-to-use-data-src-and-src

Comment: Thank you, this worked with my images. 

However, the issue seems to go deeper in that I'm realizing my stylesheet does not even appear in the <head>.  This seems like WP or php specific issue that it's no longer referencing that fire.