# Automatically updating the URL of data-src in HTML from Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am reading an XML file through and AJAX call in a Jquery to get the **productID** and other details about the product.

XML file:
    
    
     
      12345456
      some description of the product
      some manufacturer
     
     
      67687689
      some description of this product
      some manufacturer of this product

I want the image in data-src in the  tag to be the URL of the image file that is in the format of the value of the productID.png, where the productID is the value read from the XML file in the Jquery.

**Here's the HTML that I have**

```
    <img id="imageFile" src="http://www.mydomain.com/images/waitToLoad.gif" data-src="imgFile" width="300" height="300"/>
```

The Jquery is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/productcontent.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find('row').each(function () {
                var productID = $(this).find('productID').text();            
                var description = $(this).find('description').text();
                var manufacturer = $(this).find('manufacturer').text();
            $('img#imageFile').data('src',  '"http://mydomain.com/images/Products/' + productID + '.png"');
                return false;
                }
        };
    });
```

Essentially, I am trying to construct the value of "imageFile" with whatever productID is read from the XML file and have the HTML line be interpreted as 
  for the first record in the XML file and 
 for the second record.

However with the Jquery code above, I am not getting the right URL being formed for data-src in the HTML file and image of the product is not showing up. The pathnames are correct for the image file and the filenames are in the right folder as 67687689.png and 12345456.png.

Can anyone provide me with the guidance to fix the problem? thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#imageFile").attr('data-src', 'http://mydomain.com/images/Products/' + productID + '.png');
```

- Edit 1

Try :

```
$("#imageFile").attr('src', 'http://mydomain.com/images/Products/' + productID + '.png');
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it and it is generating the error "Failed to load resource : server responded with a 404 : http://mydomain.com/Products/imgFile".  Essentially, it is unable to figure out in the HTML that "imgFile" is actually http://mydomain.com/images/Products/12345456.png and considering as if "imgFile" is a file in the same directory as the HTML file which it is not.

Comment: @Joy okay that's weird. but insteat of changing the `data-src` don't you want to change the attribute `src` ? Because the `src` attribute is defined in HTML specs, and it has a functional meaning and `data-src` attribute is just one of the infinite set of data-* attributes, which have no defined meaning but can be used to include invisible data in an element, for use in scripting (or styling). See : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320052/what-are-all-the-differences-between-src-and-data-src-attributes)

Comment: src is the image that is my default gif that essentially is an hourglass. the data-src comes from the data() definition in jQuery as we you and in data-src is where the pathname to the actual image is to be stored.