# Bootstrap Carousel 500 x 500

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm kind of newbie with CSS and HTML5, I'm using Bootstrap Carousel as my template for the site I'm building and I'm having issues with the 500 x 500 picture, I don't really know how to replace it, it seems like its JavaScript or something, i was wonder if someone can light my way here..

This is the template: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/
Below is the image of the picture I'm trying to replace.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AoxZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following snippet contains the image:

```
<img class="featurette-image img-responsive" data-src="holder.js/500x500/auto" alt="500x500" src="data:image/svg+xml" data-holder-rendered="true">
```

You should change the `src` value to where your image is, not the `data-src`. The `data-src` attribute is used to include invisible data in an element. You can [read more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320052/what-are-all-the-differences-between-src-and-data-src-attributes).

Comment: Thanks for that Topr! On my template I didn't had the src value, I have just added it to the line code and it did the work!

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
<img class="featurette-image img-responsive" ng-src="your-image-path.png" alt="Generic placeholder image">
```