# Jekyll using data-src for images

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

Using Jekyll I'm trying to use `data-src` instead of `src` for all my images.

What's the best way to go for it? Create my own plugin? 
I don't think using an include is a great option...

Right now I'm adding the images like this:

```
![my alt text]({{"http://example.com/myImage.gif"}})
```

I've seen [related issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152230/support-for-adding-lazy-load-for-images-in-markdown/32154362) but the answers always recommend to use external libraries. Isn't there any more straight forward way to go for it?

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @JoostS you can create a plugin, more specifically a *custom liquid tag*.

For example using:

```
<p>{% render_img http://example.com/myImage.gif "my alt text" %}</p>
```

You can have the `render_img` plugin in `_plugins/images.rb`:

```
module Jekyll
  class RenderImgTag < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, variables, tokens)
      super
      @variables = variables.split(" ", 2)
      @url = @variables[0]
      @alt = @variables[1]
    end

    def render(context)
      "<img data-src='#{@url}' alt='#{@alt}' />"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('render_img', Jekyll::RenderImgTag)
```

Comment: Thank you. Work it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think that that creating your own plugins is the (only) right solution here. Includes cause polluted content and javascript is not really an option here.

Comment: Regarding the creation of plugins.. i don't really find very clear or straight forward docs. I'm having issues creating a `<img` tag. Even when using `  <<-MARKUP.strip` it seems it renders encoded.