# jQuery plugin overrided background image

Tags: jquery

I had some parallax effect on clone website that i am making, and i wanted to do smooth mouse wheel effect, and when i added jquery code, that overrided my background image which is supposed to be moving with scroll
jQuery code:

What part of this code is responsible for making my background white?

```
$.fn.easeScroll = function(options) {
    ! function() {
        function e() {
            var e = !1;
            e && c("keydown", r), v.keyboardSupport && !e && u("keydown", r)
        }

        function t() {
            if (document.body) {
                var t = document.body,
                    o = document.documentElement,
                    n = window.innerHeight,
                    r = t.scrollHeight;
                if (S = document.compatMode.indexOf("CSS") >= 0 ? o : t, w = t, e(), x = !0, top != self) y = !0;
                else if (r > n && (t.offsetHeight <= n || o.offsetHeight <= n)) {
                    var a = !1,
                        i = function() {
                            a || o.scrollHeight == document.height || (a = !0, setTimeout(function() {
                                o.style.height = document.height + "px", a = !1
                            }, 100))
                        };
                    if (o.style.height = "auto", setTimeout(i, 10), S.offsetHeight <= n) {
                        var l = document.createElement("div");
                        l.style.clear = "both", t.appendChild(l)
                    }
                }
                v.fixedBackground || b || (t.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll", o.style.backgroundAttachment = "scroll")
            }
        }

        function o(e, t, o, n) {
            if (n || (n = 1e3), d(t, o), 1 != v.accelerationMax) {
                var r = +new Date,
                    a = r - C;
                if (a < v.accelerationDelta) {
                    var i = (1 + 30 / a) / 2;
                    i > 1 && (i = Math.min(i, v.accelerationMax), t *= i, o *= i)
                }
                C = +new Date
            }
            if (M.push({
                x: t,
                y: o,
                lastX: 0 > t ? .99 : -.99,
                lastY: 0 > o ? .99 : -.99,
                start: +new Date
            }), !T) {
                var l = e === document.body,
                    u = function() {
                        for (var r = +new Date, a = 0, i = 0, c = 0; c < M.length; c++) {
                            var s = M[c],
                                d = r - s.start,
                                f = d >= v.animationTime,
                                h = f ? 1 : d / v.animationTime;
                            v.pulseAlgorithm && (h = p(h));
                            var m = s.x * h - s.lastX >> 0,
                                w = s.y * h - s.lastY >> 0;
                            a += m, i += w, s.lastX += m, s.lastY += w, f && (M.splice(c, 1), c--)
                        }
                        l ? window.scrollBy(a, i) : (a && (e.scrollLeft += a), i && (e.scrollTop += i)), t || o || (M = []), M.length ? E(u, e, n / v.frameRate + 1) : T = !1
                    };
                E(u, e, 0), T = !0
            }
        }

        function n(e) {
            x || t();
            var n = e.target,
                r = l(n);
            if (!r || e.defaultPrevented || s(w, "embed") || s(n, "embed") && /\.pdf/i.test(n.src)) return !0;
            var a = e.wheelDeltaX || 0,
                i = e.wheelDeltaY || 0;
            return a || i || (i = e.wheelDelta || 0), !v.touchpadSupport && f(i) ? !0 : (Math.abs(a) > 1.2 && (a *= v.stepSize / 120), Math.abs(i) > 1.2 && (i *= v.stepSize / 120), o(r, -a, -i), void e.preventDefault())
        }

        function r(e) {
            var t = e.target,
                n = e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey && e.keyCode !== H.spacebar;
            if (/input|textarea|select|embed/i.test(t.nodeName) || t.isContentEditable || e.defaultPrevented || n) return !0;
            if (s(t, "button") && e.keyCode === H.spacebar) return !0;
            var r, a = 0,
                i = 0,
                u = l(w),
                c = u.clientHeight;
            switch (u == document.body && (c = window.innerHeight), e.keyCode) {
                case H.up:
                    i = -v.arrowScroll;
                    break;
                case H.down:
                    i = v.arrowScroll;
                    break;
                case H.spacebar:
                    r = e.shiftKey ? 1 : -1, i = -r * c * .9;
                    break;
                case H.pageup:
                    i = .9 * -c;
                    break;
                case H.pagedown:
                    i = .9 * c;
                    break;
                case H.home:
                    i = -u.scrollTop;
                    break;
                case H.end:
                    var d = u.scrollHeight - u.scrollTop - c;
                    i = d > 0 ? d + 10 : 0;
                    break;
                case H.left:
                    a = -v.arrowScroll;
                    break;
                case H.right:
                    a = v.arrowScroll;
                    break;
                default:
                    return !0
            }
            o(u, a, i), e.preventDefault()
        }

        function a(e) {
            w = e.target
        }

        function i(e, t) {
            for (var o = e.length; o--;) z[N(e[o])] = t;
            return t
        }

        function l(e) {
            var t = [],
                o = S.scrollHeight;
            do {
                var n = z[N(e)];
                if (n) return i(t, n);
                if (t.push(e), o === e.scrollHeight) {
                    if (!y || S.clientHeight + 10 < o) return i(t, document.body)
                } else if (e.clientHeight + 10 < e.scrollHeight && (overflow = getComputedStyle(e, "").getPropertyValue("overflow-y"), "scroll" === overflow || "auto" === overflow)) return i(t, e)
            } while (e = e.parentNode)
        }

        function u(e, t, o) {
            window.addEventListener(e, t, o || !1)
        }

        function c(e, t, o) {
            window.removeEventListener(e, t, o || !1)
        }

        function s(e, t) {
            return (e.nodeName || "").toLowerCase() === t.toLowerCase()
        }

        function d(e, t) {
            e = e > 0 ? 1 : -1, t = t > 0 ? 1 : -1, (k.x !== e || k.y !== t) && (k.x = e, k.y = t, M = [], C = 0)
        }

        function f(e) {
            if (e) {
                e = Math.abs(e), D.push(e), D.shift(), clearTimeout(A);
                var t = D[0] == D[1] && D[1] == D[2],
                    o = h(D[0], 120) && h(D[1], 120) && h(D[2], 120);
                return !(t || o)
            }
        }

        function h(e, t) {
            return Math.floor(e / t) == e / t
        }

        function m(e) {
            var t, o, n;
            return e *= v.pulseScale, 1 > e ? t = e - (1 - Math.exp(-e)) : (o = Math.exp(-1), e -= 1, n = 1 - Math.exp(-e), t = o + n * (1 - o)), t * v.pulseNormalize
        }

        function p(e) {
            return e >= 1 ? 1 : 0 >= e ? 0 : (1 == v.pulseNormalize && (v.pulseNormalize /= m(1)), m(e))
        }

        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            frameRate: 60,
            animationTime: 1000,
            stepSize: 120,
            pulseAlgorithm: !0,
            pulseScale: 8,
            pulseNormalize: 1,
            accelerationDelta: 20,
            accelerationMax: 1,
            keyboardSupport: !0,
            arrowScroll: 50,
            touchpadSupport: !0,
            fixedBackground: !0
        }, options );

        var w, g = {
            frameRate: settings.frameRate,
            animationTime: settings.animationTime,
            stepSize: settings.stepSize,
            pulseAlgorithm: settings.pulseAlgorithm,
            pulseScale: settings.pulseScale,
            pulseNormalize: settings.pulseNormalize,
            accelerationDelta: settings.accelerationDelta,
            accelerationMax: settings.accelerationMax,
            keyboardSupport: settings.keyboardSupport,
            arrowScroll: settings.arrowScroll,
            touchpadSupport: settings.touchpadSupport,
            fixedBackground: settings.fixedBackground,
            excluded: ""
        },
            v = g,
            b = !1,
            y = !1,
            k = {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            x = !1,
            S = document.documentElement,
            D = [120, 120, 120],
            H = {
                left: 37,
                up: 38,
                right: 39,
                down: 40,
                spacebar: 32,
                pageup: 33,
                pagedown: 34,
                end: 35,
                home: 36
            },
            v = g,
            M = [],
            T = !1,
            C = +new Date,
            z = {};
        setInterval(function() {
            z = {}
        }, 1e4);
        var A, N = function() {
                var e = 0;
                return function(t) {
                    return t.uniqueID || (t.uniqueID = e++)
                }
            }(),
            E = function() {
                return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || function(e, t, o) {
                    window.setTimeout(e, o || 1e3 / 60)
                }
            }(),
            K = /chrome|iPad/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent),
            L = "onmousewheel" in document;
        L && K && (u("mousedown", a), u("mousewheel", n), u("load", t))
    }();
}

****index page****
  **This is overrided background image**
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1" data-image-src="img/Mantelzorg.png">
        <div class="parallax-inner">

            <h1 class="big_white">Design<span class="element" data-elements="4 USABILITY,4 MOTIVATION,4 INSPIRATION,4 USERS"></span>
            </h1>
            <div class="hero-copy ">Quality is free</div><span class="btn-holder">
            <a href="#" class="iva_btn hero-btn vc_btn vc_btn_md vc_btn_rounded ">Bekijk direct meer werk</a></span>
            </div>

</div>

****script part****

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.easeScroll.js"></script>

<script src="parallax.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("html").easeScroll({

  frameRate: 60,

  animationTime: 1000,

  stepSize: 120,

  pulseAlgorithm: 1,

  pulseScale: 8,

  pulseNormalize: 1,

  accelerationDelta: 20,

  accelerationMax: 1,

  keyboardSupport: true,

  arrowScroll: 50,

  touchpadSupport: true,

  fixedBackground: false

});

    </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // define variables
    var navOffset = jQuery(".header").offset().top;

    jQuery(".header").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery(".header").outerHeight());

    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){

        var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery(".header").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery(".header").removeClass("fixed");
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just add '!important' for you css background-image

```
qwerty{background: url('test') !important;}
```

Comment: But my image is not in css ...its like data-img-src atribute in index.html...and like that, doing job of background image of "parallax-window" div.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: tell me please in what block - you have your bg-image?

Comment: <div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="1" data-image-src="img/Mantelzorg.png">???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320052/what-are-all-the-differences-between-src-and-data-src-attributes,

why you don't use img tag?

Comment: Because i want parallax effect to work, and i found that in that way it works...its not my site, its a site i want to clone...

Comment: I fonund promblem. Switching from jQuery 2.x to jQuery 3.x - with 3.x I suddenly need the forced initialization.

Comment: I'm happy for you

Comment: Glad if i helped, no  problem! :)