# Element script must not have attribute async unless attribute src is also specified or unless attribute type is specified with value module

Tags: dataset, createelement

i want to load some scripts on my page when the screen is more than 760 pixels, and otherd when it is less than 760 pixels etc

i would to find the faster solution for the page

i tried to use

```
<head>
<script id="script" async data-src="../myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
function loadscript(){
let e = window.innerWidth;
if (e < 760) {
var script = document.querySelector("#script");
script.src = script.dataset.src;
}}
</script>
```

it work but the html validator dont like

is data-src reserved for images or can be used for scripts

i could use the `document.createElement('script');` solution but i am not sure it's so fast to load the page

do you know what is the best solution? is it a problem to use data-src for a script?

thanks

Comment: See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70086053/191115) on Stack Overflow, which explains it all.